# Python message without pop-up (GUI design)

Tags: python, popup, label, messagebox

I'm developing a small gambling game (in python) that needs to give feedbacks to users about how much they win/loss after their choices. I tried to use Messagebox, but it always gives pop-up, which is pretty interfering with users' experience. **Is there any way kill the pop-up window and show my message directly at the "tk" window (the root window?)**, after users made their choices?

More detail about the game: the users can choose between "choice A" and "choice B", and the program generates a win choice at random. If it's the same as users' choice, a message then shows that they win, else they lose.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to make a label on the root window and update it with a new status as needed.

Answer (score 0):

So you want change the title of the window?!
If yes:

```
root.title("Name of the window")
```

If no ->> Skip this post

Comment: I want to stop the pop-up in messagebox, just show the feedback in the default tk window.

Comment: So use Text box

Comment: Message = Text(root, bg="white", font="Arial")
Message.insert(END, "Message here")
Message.config(state=DISABLED)

And when you want insert something
Message.config(state="NORMAL")
Message.insert(END, "You won!")
Message.config(state=DISABLED)